# iOS GLKViewController Nested GLKit View

Tags: ios, view, opengl-es, controller, glkit

I used the OpenGL Game template as a starting point for my application and for various reasons I need to have the GLKView that I'm drawing to be a child view of the main view. I tried setting "self.view = glView", where glView is a nested GLKit view and linking that view to the view outlet of the GLKViewController subclass I have but I've had no luck. Can anyone tell me how I would go about making the GLKView that the GLKViewController controls a child view of that View Controller's main view? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If by child view you mean subview (it makes sense to me) just do :

```
[myViewController.view addSubview:glView];
```

(Of course if you're calling it in your view controller just use `self.view`).